# How to create a dynamic patch method in Laravel that updates data only when provided?

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I am working on a Laravel project and trying to implement a dynamic patch method to update specific fields in a model only when they are provided in the request. I have already written the following code, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient or cleaner way to achieve this:

```
public function updateShipModule(ShipModulesRequest $request, $id)
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    // Find the record by ID
    $module = ShipModules::findOrFail($id);

    // Update only the is_workable field
    if ($request->has('is_workable')) {
        $module->is_workable = $data['is_workable'];
    }

    if ($request->has('module_name')) {
        $module->module_name = $data['module_name'];
    }

    $module->save();

    return response()->json(['data' => $module]);
}
```

Additionally, I have included the following code in the validation rules of my request class to handle patch requests:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    $rules = [
        'is_workable' => 'required|boolean',
        'module_name' => 'sometimes|required|String|min:3|max:25|unique:ship_modules',
    ];

    if ($this->isMethod('patch')) {
        // Add the 'sometimes' rule for module_name
        $rules['is_workable'] = 'sometimes|' . $rules['is_workable'];
        $rules['module_name'] = 'sometimes|' . $rules['module_name'];
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

I would like to know if this approach to handling the 'sometimes' rule for the 'module_name' field in the request validation is correct and aligns with best practices.

Is there a better way to handle dynamic updates based on the provided data without explicitly checking each field? I want to keep the code clean and avoid repetition, as the number of fields may increase.

I would like to know if this approach to handling the 'sometimes' rule for the 'module_name' field in the request validation is correct and aligns with best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach aligns with Laravel's best practices. You can use the `fill` method to automatically assign the values of the validated data to the corresponding properties of the model based on the array of data provided.

```php
public function updateShipModule(ShipModulesRequest $request, $id)
{
    $data = $request->validated();

    // Find the record by ID
    $module = ShipModules::findOrFail($id);

    // Fill the model with the validated data
    $module->fill($data);

    $module->save();

    return response()->json(['data' => $module]);
}
```

You must ensure the `$fillable` property in your `ShipModules` model is defined (if it isn't already) like...

```php
protected $fillable = ['is_workable', 'module_name'];
```